# Pushing updates on exact scheduled time

Tags: php, cron

I am creating a scheduler using PHP/MySQL where I have to allow the use to select date and time for publishing the content. The requirement is, the content should get posted at the **exact scheduled time**. If I create cron job, the notifications won't go out at exact time.

Running a cron job every minute is not really feasible in my case since I have to publish using an API and that itself is time consuming.

Is there any other way I can implement to make sure that the exact time provided in scheduler is followed. One of the best example that does this is Google Calendar which sends the reminders at the time you ask for.

Aditya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating a daemon. The [PEAR System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) would be a great starting point. The daemon should essentially be a loop that queries the database, posts the content if necessary and sleeps.

Some sections of their documentation you might be interested in:

1. [What is Daemon](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.system.system-daemon.what-is-a-daemon.php)
2. [Daemons vs Cronjobs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.system.system-daemon.daemons-vs-cronjobs.php)
3. [Installation](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/download)
4. [Example](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.system.system-daemon.examples.simple.php)

Comment: Yeah, this seems better. I have used the core process functions earlier as well but I am not really how well those works and whether we can really rely on PHPs process handling capability. Have you yourself used this package in any of your real projects? If so, what's your experience with it?

Comment: @Aditya - The package is a great starting point. It has many features, makes writing the daemon simple, and it'll even take care of creating the `init.d` file for you so that it starts automatically when the system starts.

Answer (score 0):

YOU SHOULD CREATE [CRONE JOB](http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples) TO ACCOMPLISH THIS.

Comment: I have mentioned the problem with cron job in my message. So that's not an option for me.